# Flutter pub.get stopped working, even on vanilla install : socket error trying to find package xxx

Tags: flutter, dart, package

First of all, I have been working with Flutter for more than 3 years, and am a reasonably seasoned dev. Yet this baffles me, and I can’t find a solution online.

Since this morning, I systematically get this error while running `flutter pub get` ou `flutter doctor`

> pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
> Got socket error trying to find package node_preamble at https://pub.dartlang.org

I am on Big Sur 11.2.2
I wiped the Flutter sdk dir, reinstalled from the official site (latest stable), wiped the .pub-cache and removed a stand-alone dart install. Rebooted several times. Yet, I still get the problem on the first ‘Flutter doctor’
I also manually installed the `node_preamble` packages, without result.

Here and there, I find mentions of a problem with proxies but I have none and reproduced the issue using my phone’s 4g connection. I also deactivated the antivirus and went as far as using a VPN to try France and USA (I am based in Belgium).

Am I the only one ? Do you have any clue?
I would love to supply a `Flutter doctor`, but I can’t. And I am badly stuck now :/
Thanks

Comment: I tried switching to beta channel, but same result.
The initial install was via the bundle, I tried downloading via `git` and the beta channel :

```git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b beta```

Comment: The error is different this time after running `flutter doctor` :


```Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 40441def692f444660a11e20fac37af9050245ab...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  194M  100  194M    0     0  5231k      0  0:00:38  0:00:38 --:--:-- 5268k
Building flutter tool...
Got socket error trying to find package crypto at https://pub.dartlang.org.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)```

Comment: Hi I am also getting the same issue in Mac OS Big Sur, Sophos Endpoint is installed in the system by my organisation. Is any one found a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Hi, me too. I need to work but I can't because of that. And I don't have an antivirus. :(

Comment: @MárcioValim even if you don't have any antivirus software running on your computer you might still have a firewall program that is denying network permission to some component of Flutter, Dart, or your IDE.

Comment: My problem was AdGuard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was about to format my HD, I uninstalled `SOPHOS HOME` antivirus, and it solved the issue.

This is weird because another Mac computer running the same OS and the same Sophos version worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A socket error is basically a connection error. And in the case of running `flutter pub get` a socket error is very likely due to a firewall. Check your firewall settings. Ensure that no component of Flutter, Dart, or your IDE is being blocked by your firewall or antivirus program.

I encountered the same problem and found out that dart.exe was denied network permission by my firewall. After putting dart.exe on the exceptions list the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was Sophos Home.
After uninstalling it, the problem disappeared.